# downcasted pointer to member as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, casting, member-pointers

I'm working in some code using the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, where the derived class is passed up to specialize its own base classes at compile time.

With this, I run into an annoying problem which I have made a toy example for. I have annotated base::bar with comments describing the expected behavior (and why I expect it). The entire example is intended to be compiled as is, and results in 3 compiler errors (clang-3.9) as noted in the comments. For reference, $4.11/2:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv T”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, where D is a derived class (Clause 10) of B. If B is
>   an inaccessible (Clause 11), ambiguous (10.2), or virtual (10.1) base class of D, or a base class of a virtual
>   base class of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion refers
>   to the same member as the pointer to member before the conversion took place, but it refers to the base
>   class member as if it were a member of the derived class. The result refers to the member in D’s instance of B. Since the result has type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, it can be dereferenced with a D object.
>   The result is the same as if the pointer to member of B were dereferenced with the B subobject of D. The
>   null member pointer value is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type.57

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename impl_t>
struct super
{
        typedef int impl_t::* member_dat_t;

    protected:
        template<member_dat_t dat>
        int foo()
        {
                return static_cast<impl_t *>(this)->*dat;
        }
};

template<typename impl_t>
struct base : super<impl_t>
{
        using this_t = base<impl_t>;
        int base_dat = 0;

        int bar()
        {
                // This, of course, succeeds
                this-> template foo<&impl_t::derived_dat>();

                // This fails during template instantiation, because the compiler knows that the
                // location of base_dat/base_func is in the base<derived> subobject of a derived
                // object rather than derived itself.
                this-> template foo<&impl_t::base_dat>();
                // (i.e., this succeeds, despite the address being taken on a member resolved off the impl_t)
                static_assert(std::is_same<int this_t::*, decltype((&impl_t::base_dat))>::value, "");

                // But what if we cast, as the standard (N3242) permits in $4.11/2 [conv.mem]
                // Now, these succeed
                static_assert(std::is_same<int impl_t::*, decltype((static_cast<int impl_t::*>(&impl_t::base_dat)))>::value, "");
                static_assert(std::is_same<typename super<impl_t>::member_dat_t, decltype((static_cast<int impl_t::*>(&impl_t::base_dat)))>::value, "");
                // But these still fail
                this-> template foo<static_cast<int impl_t::*>(&impl_t::base_dat)>();
                this-> template foo<static_cast<typename super<impl_t>::member_dat_t>(&impl_t::base_dat)>();
                return 1;
        }
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
        int derived_dat;
};

void test()
{
        derived d;
        d.bar();
}
```

For the "why": the existing code in `base` only ever instantiates `super::foo` with members actually defined in `derived`. It would please me if I could also use members defined in `base<derived>`, inherited by `derived`. The actual code is using member functions, but member data sufficed for the example.

Edit:
I've technically come up with a solution that should work. Basically, `base` derives from `super<base<impl_t>>` instead of `super<impl_t>`, so now we can invoke `foo` with members of `base<impl_t>`, and if we need different behavior from the most-derived classes, we can make the methods in base virtual. But this throws away a little of the benefit of CRTP (we now have VTBL in the objects, and the cost of dynamic polymorphism, even when we know at compile time what we want).

Thanks